# C++ Max size of array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size, max

```
const unsigned int PATRON_TABLE_SIZE = 10001;
Patron* patronTable[PATRON_TABLE_SIZE];
```

Patron is a class containing basic info.  I checked the pointer at patronTable[500] and it is NULL, but the pointer at patronTable[5000] is not NULL.  I can't find any info about why this is the way it is.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you initialize the `patronTable`?

Comment: just because you defined a table doesn't mean it'll actually be FILLED. in fact, it's full of whatever random garbage is left in the memory location the array's now occupying, and your null/not null stuff will randomly change each time you run the program.

Answer (score 2):

c++ doesn't automatically initialize the array of pointers to any set value (unless you explicitely tell it to). So what you are seeing ist just random garbage which happened to occupy the space where the array was allocated. `patronTable` is `PATRON_TABLE_SIZE` long, just like you told it to be

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C++ that are not global or declared static are not initialized by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you program unmanaged (not .NET) code, the memory isn't cleared. If you want all array elements to be NULL do something like `memset(patronTable, 0, PATRON_TABLE_SIZE * sizeof(Patron[0]));`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the content of your array by

```
Patron* patronTable[PATRON_TABLE_SIZE] = { };
```

That will set all the values to zero.